Is a comma used to join dependent clauses?
In a sentence A:

She played with our dog, and he played with our cat.

One would typically put a comma before “and” as two independent clauses are joined, if I get the rules correctly.
Does it change if this sentence is made into a subordinate clause, for example like in this sentence B:

They came to our house where she played with our dog and he played with our cat.

Or this sentece C:

It was the house where she played with our dog and he played with our cat.

Should there be a comma in front of “and” or not in sentences B and C?

The dog and cat are independent but short. I'd use a comma before the "where," to hold the logic in place.

Are you sure they are independent clauses as per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_clause ?
I reworded the question to make it clearer what I am after. Or is that rule "put comma in front of For, And, Nor, But, Or, Yet, So when they join independent clauses absolute?

@sup Oftentimes, writers confuse coordinating conjunctions with subordinating conjunctions and another type of word known as relative pronouns. All three of these types of words have different rules when it comes to using commas:
Coordinating conjunctions always use a comma when connecting independent clauses.
Subordinating conjunctions don’t use a comma unless they are used to begin a sentence.
Relative pronouns might use a comma. It depends on if they introduce a restrictive or nonrestrictive relative clause.

In answer to the question in your title - no, a comma is not used to join two dependent clauses. Dependent clauses cannot stand alone as complete sentences and typically need to be connected to an independent clause.
You're right about example A - the fact that one person played with a dog and the other played with a cat are two independent clauses that could stand alone, so the comma goes before the conjunction 'and'.
But in examples B and C those are not two separate clauses - it is one clause collectively detailing what went on at the house, and it is dependent on the main clause before it. Because it is one clause it should not be broken by a comma.

I thought that "clause" is basically defined as a unit of meaning that has a subject and a predicate in agreement, so sentences B and C have three clauses in them, no?

Comma rules for relative (adjective) clauses
OP gave two sentences, both of which contain adjective clauses.. Adjective clauses may be restrictive or non-restrictive.
Ref. 21st Century English, Burlington English

Restrictive Clause.
A restrictive clause provides necessary information about a noun in the sentence. It is sometimes referred to as an essential clause because it cannot be removed from the sentence without changing the meaning of the sentence. No punctuation is needed in this sentence.
Example: The boy who sits at the back of the classroom asks very few questions.
Non-restrictive clause.
A non-restrictive clause adds information to a sentence that is not essential to the overall meaning of the sentence, and the sentence can convey the same information without the use of this clause. It uses commas to show that the information is additional.
Example: My pet dog, which is a poodle, got lost from the park.

Now applying the rules to OP's sentences.
First sentence

1. They came to our house, where she played with our dog, and he played with our cat..

The adjective clause is non-restrictive because 'our house' identifies the noun. The clause only describes the noun, so a comma is required before where

2. It was the house where she played with our dog, and he played with our cat.

This adjective clause is restrictive so a comma is not required.
In both cases, comma is required before coordinating conjunction 'and'
Compound-complex sentences will typically be joined together with a coordinating conjunction as you would use in a compound sentence, with the comma placed immediately before the coordinating conjunction.
https://www.masterclass.com/articles/compound-complex-sentence-guide

Thank you, this is an answer I was looking for. However, my example sentences are just complex sentences, no? https://www.masterclass.com/articles/complex-sentence-guide they have one independent clause and two dependent ones.

It is compound-complex sentence as the two dependent clauses are connected with a coordinating conjunction. (and)

Hm, I cannot find examples that have have too dependent clauses at the same level
both attaching to the independent clause), but the definitions seem to agree tha for a complex-compound sentence, you need at least two independent clauses, but in my example both "where she played with our dog" and "[where]  he played with our cat" are dependent clauses, so it does not seem to fall under the definition of complex-compound sentence. Not that it matter for the comma-writiing purposes.

3 Compound-Complex Sentence Examples
Compound-complex sentences can clearly convey more information than your standard compound or complex sentence. Here are some examples of compound-complex sentences.
Your sentence is similar. It contains 3 clauses.
https://www.masterclass.com/articles/compound-complex-sentence-guide

Well, those have again two independent clauses and one dependent one, unlike mine. "I went home, where I cooked dinner, which was delicious."Is a complex sentence with two subordinate clauses (to the "first-level" independent clause and to "second-level" subordinate clause. "I went home. where I cooked dinner and where I took a shower" is the same, just the subordinate clauses depend on the independent one (both are on second level).  In my original sentences, "he played with our cat" is not independent, because he played with the cat in the house. Both players are on the second level.

I am not sure but I think you may be right. Your sentence has one main clause and two dependent clauses. So it is only a complex sentence.

@sup : Did my reply answer your question? I knew about restrictive and non restrictive clauses, but I enjoyed doing more research on it.

Well, I am now more confident I should write a comma before and, so in that sense it did, I just think the rationale is a bit questionable as it uses complex-compound sentences. If you edit that, I would of course accept it as a valid and correct answer.

@sup In sentences A, B and C, I would put one, one, and no commas, respectively. If omitting the comma after "dog" in sentences B and C actually breaks the rule (as currently claimed in this answer), so be it, because adding a comma there potentially adds ambiguity without adding value.

The rule is : Always use a comma before a coordinating conjunction
The seven coordinating conjunctions are for, and, nor, but, or, yet, and so. It helps to remember them as the FANBOYS. If any of these seven words are connecting independent clauses, they must have a comma before them.

Can coordinating conjunctions join dependent and independent clauses?
Coordinating conjunctions join grammatically similar elements (two nouns, two verbs, two modifiers, two independent clauses): and. or. nor.
https://writing.wisc.edu/handbook/coordconj/#:~:text=Coordinating%20conjunctions%20join%20grammatically%20similar,nor

I think that for sure the FANBOYS rule only applies to independet clauses. All sources seem to be silent about joining dependent clauses. I can see why @ryang says comma adds ambiguity - it then might be interpretted the playing with the cat takes place outside of the house. Maybe the right answer would be that it comes down to an individual preference? Dunno.

If a clause with coordinating conjunction (Fanboys) then it is independent clause. As per rule, dependent clause cannot start with a coordinating conjunction.
